# While not (or equivalent) java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm making a program with Java that needs to involve some error checking. I can stop users from entering bad numerical inputs like this (assume the `input` scanner has already been created):

```
while (n == 0){
    System.out.println("Can't use 0 as a denominator! Please enter a real, nonzero number");
    n = input.nextInt();
}
```

But how do I stop users from entering an invalid string? I can't use `!=`, because strings can only be compared with the `string.equals()` method, right? So, is there a while not loop? ie:

```
while !(string.equals("y") || string.equals("n")){
   //here have code
}
```

Or something of that nature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there is no such thing as a while-not loop, you can always invert the condition:

```
while (!(string.equals("y") || string.equals("n"))){
```

This is read, "while the string is not equal to "y" or "n"".

You could also apply DeMorgan's identity to rewrite this as:

```
while (!(string.equals("y")) && !(string.equals("n"))){
```

which is a bit clearer as "While the string isn't equal to "y" and isn't equal to "n"".

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a `while-not` instruction, but you can simply negate the condition in a normal `while` loop. Try this:

```
while (!string.equals("y") && !string.equals("n"))
```

Or even better, to guard against the case where the string is `null` and/or it's in a different case:

```
while (!"y".equalsIgnoreCase(string) && !"n".equalsIgnoreCase(string))
```

Answer (score 3):

You almost get it, just change where you position your `!`
like this:

```
while (!(string.equals("y") || string.equals("n")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try regex?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String string = sc.nextLine();
while (!string.matches("(?i)^(?:y|n|yes|no)$"))
{
    System.out.println("Invalid input...");
    string = sc.nextLine();
}
boolean answer = string.matches("(?i)^(?:y|yes)$");
```